# Не работает stoi в Xcode C++

Tags: c++, xcode

Подскажите пожалуйста почему Xcode на маке ругается на `stoi`?

Пишет следующее:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
> terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
> (lldb)

```
void Read(vector<Car>& cars, vector<Bike>& bikes)
{
    string s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6;
    ifstream file("transports.csv");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        getline(file, s1, ';');
        getline(file, s2, ';');
        getline(file, s3, ';');
        getline(file, s4, ';');
        getline(file, s5, ';');
        getline(file, s6);
        cars.push_back(Car(s1, stoi(s2), stoi(s3), stoi(s4), stoi(s5), s6));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        getline(file, s1, ';');
        getline(file, s2, ';');
        getline(file, s3, ';');
        getline(file, s4, ';');
        getline(file, s5);
        bikes.push_back(Bike(s1, stoi(s2), stoi(s3), stoi(s4), s5));
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: такое может быть, если в stoi передать пустую строку или к примеру буквы. Показывайте Ваш transports.csv

Comment: Программа прекрасно работает в других IDE (Visusal studio на винде и VSCode на макоси). Компилятор просто не видит stoi, как мне сказали в Xcode ее просто не существует. Вот сижу теперь, пытаюсь написать свою функцию перевода string в int.

Comment: Вы понимаете разницу между ошибкой компиляции и ошибкой выполнения? то, что Вы пишите в вопросе - это ошибка выполнения. Значит код уже скомпилился.

Answer (score -1):

Как и написал в комментариях к вопросу, решил написать свой конвертер из `string` в `int`.
 И вот что у меня получилось:

```
int toInt(string str)
{
    int count = 0, value = 0;
    bool check = false, err = false;        
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(str[i])) err = true;
    }
    if (err == false)
    {
        int* arr = new int[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            arr[i] = (int)str[i] - 48;
        }
        int modif = arr[str.length()-1];
        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {   
            modif = arr[i] * count;
            if (check == false) modif = arr[i];
            value = value + modif;
            if (check == false) count = 10;
            else count *= 10;
            check = true;
        }
        delete[]arr;
        return value;
    }
    else cout << "Ошибка! toInt принимает только строки с целочисленными значениями" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Как ни странно это работает, однако есть зелененькое предупреждение `C6386: Переполнение буфера при записи в "arr"...` Не знаю может ли мне где-то это потом вылезти боком, пока что не сильно понимаю в работе памяти. Если кто шарит подскажите пожалуйста есть ли риски в работе с такой функцией и если да, то как поправить это предупреждение?

Comment: Код у Вас откровенно плохой. Лишнее выделение памяти...

Comment: У вас память утекает. Лучше `stoi` починить, а не велосипеды делать...

Comment: Интересно, это проблема только РУ комьюнити? Все могут только умничать, тыкая пальцем в небо, что они считают что что-то неправильно, а на деле помочь разобраться что конкретно и как исправить никто не может. Зачем вы пишете?

Comment: @Antares По-первых, когда отвечаете, пишите в начале сообщения `@username`, а то нам уведомления не приходят и мы можем не ответить. Во-вторых, если вам что-то непонятно, то не ругайтесь, а просто спросите (*"@holyblackcat Где именно утечка?"* - вы забыли `delete[] arr;` для массива).

Comment: На счет `stoi` - можете показать входной файл? И хорошо бы дополнить код в вопросе, чтобы мы могли его скомпилировать (весь код вываливать не надо, почитайте про [mcve]).

Comment: @holyblackcat Спасибо что указали на утечку. Извиняюсь. Сейчас попробую написать краткий пример, чтобы Вы смогли запустить его. Отпишу в комменты когда будет готово

Comment: `тыкая пальцем в небо` Первым же комментарием к вашему вопросу написали возможные причины: `такое может быть, если в stoi передать пустую строку или к примеру буквы`. И это не пальцем в небо, это требование стандарта языка. Если не удалось преобразовать строку в число, то генерируется исключение `std::invalid_argument`. Смотрите [раздел `exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) на cppreference.com, либо сразу стандарт языка, [string.conversions/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.conversions#3).

Comment: `а на деле помочь разобраться что конкретно и как исправить никто не может` Угу, никто, ну кроме быть может того самого первого комментария, в котором вам написали, что делать:  `Показывайте Ваш transports.csv`.  Если `stoi` генерирует исключение, то нужно смотреть строку, которая ей передаётся.

Comment: @wololo Серьезно, дело не в `transports.csv`, т.к. далее я его совсем убрал и стал отправлять в `stoi` обычные строки, но проблема не исчезла. Через `toInt()` (костыль, написанный мной) же все работает нормально.
Моя проблема, получается глубже. Дело в том что я пытаюсь кодить в плюсах на маке – так уж вышло, а тут половина фукционала недоступна.

Comment: Все тело Вашей функции в целом сводится к `int r = 0; for (char c : s) { r = r*10+c-'0';} return r;`, ну ещё можно isdigit добавить, что бы отбросить плохие символы. Я знаю, что мак это не очень удачная система обучения программирования, но я сильно-сильно сомневаюсь, что там "не работает stoi". Также, мне кажется, что Вы не понимаете разницу между компиляцией и собственно запуском,  не предоставили исходные данные (`stoi("плохие символы")` уже было бы достаточно), поэтому Вам никто и не может помочь.